# ggplot unexpectedly graphing something on y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm stuck on the values ggplot is graphing on the y-axis and can't see the issue.

**Reprex:**
Here is the head output of my data frame, followed by dput and code.

```
> head(my_df)
        Date        Asset Value  pos_neg   qtr_date    yr_date
1 2018-09-01 real_gdp_yoy   3.2 positive 2018-07-01 2018-01-01
2 2018-09-02 real_gdp_yoy   3.2 positive 2018-07-01 2018-01-01
3 2018-09-03 real_gdp_yoy   3.2 positive 2018-07-01 2018-01-01
4 2018-09-04 real_gdp_yoy   3.2 positive 2018-07-01 2018-01-01
5 2018-09-05 real_gdp_yoy   3.2 positive 2018-07-01 2018-01-01
6 2018-09-06 real_gdp_yoy   3.2 positive 2018-07-01 2018-01-01
```

**The problem:** I expected the y data (Value) graphed to be 3.2, 3.1, and 2.5.  However, ggplot looks like it is graphing different numbers altogether.  It's probably a simple error but I am missing it.

```
my_df <-  
  structure(list(Date = structure(c(17775, 17776, 17777, 17778, 17779, 17780, 17781, 17782, 17783, 
                                    17784, 17785, 17786, 17787, 17788, 17789, 17790, 17791, 17792, 
                                    17793, 17794, 17795, 17796, 17797, 17798, 17799, 17800, 17801, 
                                    17802, 17803, 17804, 17805, 17806, 17807, 17808, 17809, 17810, 
                                    17811, 17812, 17813, 17814, 17815, 17816, 17817, 17818, 17819, 
                                    17820, 17821, 17822, 17823, 17824, 17825, 17826, 17827, 17828, 
                                    17829, 17830, 17831, 17832, 17833, 17834, 17835, 17836, 17837, 
                                    17838, 17839, 17840, 17841, 17842, 17843, 17844, 17845, 17846, 
                                    17847, 17848, 17849, 17850, 17851, 17852, 17853, 17854, 17855, 
                                    17856, 17857, 17858, 17859, 17860, 17861, 17862, 17863, 17864, 
                                    17865, 17866, 17867, 17868, 17869, 17870, 17871, 17872, 17873, 
                                    17874, 17875, 17876, 17877, 17878, 17879, 17880, 17881, 17882, 
                                    17883, 17884, 17885, 17886, 17887, 17888, 17889, 17890, 17891, 
                                    17892, 17893, 17894, 17895, 17896, 17897), class = "Date"), 
                 Asset = c("real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", 
                           "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy", "real_gdp_yoy"), 
                 Value = c(3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 
                           3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 
                           3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 
                           3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 
                           3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 
                           3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 
                           3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 
                           3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 
                           3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 
                           3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 2.5, 2.5), 
                 pos_neg = c("positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
                             "positive", "positive", "positive"), 
                 qtr_date = structure(c(17713, 17713, 17713, 17713, 17713, 17713, 17713, 
                                        17713, 17713, 17713, 17713, 17713, 17713, 17713, 
                                        17713, 17713, 17713, 17713, 17713, 17713, 17713, 
                                        17713, 17713, 17713, 17713, 17713, 17713, 17713, 
                                        17713, 17713, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 
                                        17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 
                                        17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 
                                        17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 
                                        17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 
                                        17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 
                                        17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 
                                        17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 
                                        17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 
                                        17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 
                                        17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 
                                        17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 
                                        17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 17805, 
                                        17805, 17805, 17805, 17897), class = "Date"), 
                 yr_date = structure(c(17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                                       17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                                       17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                                       17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                                       17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                                       17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                                       17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                                       17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                                       17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                                       17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                                       17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                                       17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                                       17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                                       17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                                       17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                                       17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                                       17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                                       17532, 17532, 17532, 17897), class = "Date")), 
            row.names = c(NA, -123L), class = "data.frame")




# Color bars based on postive or negative values
mycolors  <- c("positive" = "seagreen4", "negative" = "firebrick4")


# Plot
p <- ggplot(my_df, aes(x = qtr_date, y = Value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = pos_neg), alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
p
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Probably `ggplot` just added every number (with the same `x`) together?

Comment: `geom_col()` uses stacked bars by default, so I'm guessing all your individual values for each `qtr_date` are stacked on top of each other.  Do you want a single bar for each quarter?  If so you may want to summarize your data so you have a single row instead of many rows per qtr_date.

Comment: Yes, I wanted a single bar for each quarter.  I see, you think it is aggregating all of the values on the quarter end date vs. graphing the single unchanging value of the quarter?  I could have sworn I used this approach before and ggplot handled it correctly

Comment: You're plotting daily data, but say you only want it by quarter. For any given quarter, you have the same value multiple times, so it gets stacked. You can just take the distinct set of quarters and values, then use that

Comment: Thank you all.  That was driving me nuts. Using position = "dodge" clears this up as well (although technically makes the alpha=0.7 less useful):   # Plot
p <- ggplot(my_df, aes(x = qtr_date, y = Value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = pos_neg),
           alpha = 0.7,
           position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
p

Comment: And my final comment in case someone else has the same issue:  to easily aggregate and plot, one can use distinct:    my_df2 <- my_df %>%
    distinct(qtr_date, .keep_all = TRUE) and then plot using my_df2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have repeated values within each quarter date. The graph is showing the sum of value by quarter.

```
library(tidyverse)
my_df %>% 
    group_by(qtr_date) %>% 
    summarize(sum(Value))
```

You should aggregate the data to the quarter level before plotting it.